# Limit the amount of menus someone can make

Tags: menus

Working on a site of mine I was wondering if it would be possible to set/limit the amount of menus someone can make to '1' (and thereby disabling the current menu location features)?

I've been looking at `nav-menus.php` and have noticed

```
$nav_menus = wp_get_nav_menus( array('orderby' => 'name') );
$menu_count = count( $nav_menus );
```

and know I am probably looking for a way to filter `wp_get_nav_menus`, but I'm not entirely sure if this would be the best way, or how to do this best.

Could someone perhaps assist me with this?

Comment: Why? The theme controls the menu locations so if the theme supports one location, only one menu will work no matter how many are created in the backend.

Comment: That's somewhat the reason why I've been asked. People get confused seeing the option to create multiple menus (of which they can only use one at the time), and having just a single location. Now I can explain them (which I have), but since it's also not used I prefer removing it to a bare minimal set of options.

Comment: Maybe someone is more familiar with this subsystem than me but I took a look around the source my feeling is that you are in for something a _lot_ more painful than explaining how menus work. :)